# Programming in C finding smallest value in random array?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Part of my program is designed to output the smallest and largest values in an array stored with random numbers. My program outputs the largest value in the array just fine but when it comes to outputting the smallest value, it outputs some garbage. I've searched the website and I would figure it should work just fine based off what I have found. Here is my code I'd appreciate the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <time.h>  

int main(void){
    int randomNumbers[100];
    double average;
    int highest, smallest;
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int min, max;
    srand(time(NULL));       
    printf("Enter min and max respectively: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);
    smallest = highest = randomNumbers[0];
    for (i; i < 100; i++){
        randomNumbers[i] = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min; 
        sum = sum + randomNumbers[i];

        if (highest < randomNumbers[i]){
            highest = randomNumbers[i];
        }

        if (smallest > randomNumbers[i]){
            smallest = randomNumbers[i];
        }

        printf("%d ", randomNumbers[i]);
        if (i == 9 || i == 19 || i == 29 || i == 39 || i == 49 || i ==59 || i == 69 || i ==79 || i == 89)
            printf("\n");

    } 
    average = sum / 100;
    printf("\nAverage: %lf", average);
    printf("\nHighest: %d", highest);
    printf("\nSmallest: %d", smallest);

}
```

Comment: `smallest = highest = randomNumbers[0];` is before `randomNumbers[0] = rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;`.

Comment: Also, `if (i == 9 || i == 19 || i == 29 || i == 39 || i == 49 || i ==59 || i == 69 || i ==79 || i == 89)` is not very maintainable. `if (i % 10 == 9)` does the same thing better.

Comment: Wouldn't putting it in the loop and after that store smallest and highest as the initial element of the array every time it goes through the loop though?

Comment: This is what debuggers are for.

Comment: It would, if you just plop it in. Good thing there is something that tells you whether this is your first run through the loop, or 99th. Or if you do as John Zwinck says, and do it in two separate loops.  `</hint>`

Comment: oh wait I figured it out thank you for the advice Amadan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your initialization:

```
smallest = highest = randomNumbers[0];
```

`randomNumbers` has not yet been populated at that point.  It might be clearer if you populated all the numbers first.